# Vuetify dialog plays both videos in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-for that loops through a media array to play a video. Currently my v-dialog opens both models one over the other. It also keeps playing the video after the dialog is closed. Any idea how to stop both videos being loaded into the same dialog?

```
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item
      v-for="media in media"
      :key="media.title"
      class="mb-2"
    >
      <v-list-item-action>
          <v-dialog
            v-model="videoDialog"
            persistent
            width="800px"
            :retain-focus="false"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
              >
                <v-icon>mdi-open-in-new</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <Video
                :video-url="media.url"
              />
            </v-card>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer />
              <v-btn
                color="primary"
                text
                @click="videoDialog = false"
              >
                Close
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-dialog>
      </v-list-item-action>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
```

... and below I have a media array I want to loop over and add the url into the

```
 data: () => ({
    media: [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Exploring the culture at GSK',
        url: 'https://youtu.be/RBdgq5VTQmM'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'The meaning of digital innovation: the pharmaphorum podcast',
        url: 'https://youtu.be/XJSWx31V3so'
      }]

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your data add a extra prop for show the dialog:

```js
data: () => ({
    media: [
      {
        id: 0,
        title: "Exploring the culture at GSK",
        show: false,
        url: "https://youtu.be/RBdgq5VTQmM",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        show: false,
        title: "The meaning of digital innovation: the pharmaphorum podcast",
        url: "https://youtu.be/XJSWx31V3so",
      },
    ],
```

and bind your v-model in your template like this:

```html
<v-dialog
            v-model="media.show" <-----
            persistent
            width="800px"
            :retain-focus="false"
          >
```

while handling the `show:true/false` make sure only one dialog at a time is `show:true`